# python async loop to send udp payload every 15 seconds, and stop trying after 60 seconds

Tags: python, python-asyncio

**My objective** is to create an async loop that connects to UDP ip addresses and receive the response. However, if the response is not received within 15 seconds, resend the request again, and stop trying after 60 seconds.

**main.py**

```
async def main():
    tasks = []
    for i, l in zip(result["tr"], range(len(result["tr"]))):
        task = create_task(udp.connect(urlparse(i).hostname, urlparse(i).port))
        tasks.append(task)

    done, pending = await wait(tasks)
    for i in done:
        print(i.result())
```

**udpClient.py**

```
async def connect(udp, port):
    payload = b'sample_data_input'
    on_conn_lost, datagram_data = loop.create_future(), loop.create_future()

    transport, protocol = await self.default_event_loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
        lambda: ProtocolFactoryUDP(payload, on_conn_lost, datagram_data),
        remote_addr=(str(udp), int(port)))

    try:
        await on_conn_lost
        return datagram_data
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

**ProtocolFactoryUDP**  -> [This is same as the example on python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#udp-echo-client)

```
class ProtocolFactoryUDP:
    def __init__(self, message, on_con_lost):
        self.message = message
        self.on_con_lost = on_con_lost
        self.transport = None
        self.datagram_data = datagram_data

    def connection_made(self, transport):
        self.transport = transport
        print('Send:', self.message)
        self.transport.sendto(self.message.encode())

    def datagram_received(self, data, addr):
        print("Received:", data.decode())
        self.datagram_data.set_result((data, addr))
        print("Close the socket")
        self.transport.close()

    def error_received(self, exc):
        print('Error received:', exc)

    def connection_lost(self, exc):
        print("Connection closed")
        self.on_con_lost.set_result(True)
```

Currently, this code lets me connect to the UDP targets and print out the response.

However, this doesn't achieve my objective, because if the server doesn't respond with anything / takes too long to respond, the udpClient just ends up waiting there forever. How can I create an async loop such that if the response is not received within 15 seconds, resend the request again, and quit with an empty payload (or quit gracefully) after 60 seconds of trying.

**Edit 1 with updated code from paul**

**main.py**

```
for i, l in zip(result["tr"], range(len(result["tr"]))):
    task = create_task(udp.connect(urlparse(i).hostname, urlparse(i).port))
    tasks.append(task)

for f in as_completed(tasks):
    result = await f
```

**udpClient.py**

```
...
for _ in range(4):
    try:
        transport, protocol = await self.default_event_loop.create_datagram_endpoint(
            lambda: ProtocolFactoryUDP(payload, on_conn_lost, datagram_data),
            remote_addr=(str(udp), int(port)))

        await asyncio.wait_for(on_conn_lost, 15.0)  # -> Met with CancelledError here.. 
        return datagram_data
    except TimeoutError:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You've given a perfect description of what you are trying to do, and that's often the hardest part.  To reduce it to code, you might look at the asyncio.wait_for function, and also the asyncio.as_completed function.  Here is a sketch of what I think you want.  I leave the UDP details to you.

The wait_for function takes a timeout value (15s in your case).  You want to try 4 times, so all you need is a simple for loop.  You catch the TimeoutError and repeat the loop; let other errors propagate back to the caller.  If you don't get a timeout you just return, which terminates the task.

You can print the results as they complete, or wait until they are all completed by using asyncio.gather(return_exceptions=True).

```
async def main():
    tasks = []
    for i, l in zip(result["tr"], range(len(result["tr"]))):
        coro = my_task(udp.connect(urlparse(i).hostname, urlparse(i).port))
        tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(coro))

    for i in asyncio.as_completed(tasks):
        print(i.result())

async def my_task(host, port):
    for _ in range(4):
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(do_something_with_udp(host, port), 15.0)
            return
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            pass
```

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for this! I'm trying to implement your solution, but i'm met with an error. Firstly, I think `i.result()` in `asyncio.as_completed` needs to be awaited. According to the docs - but i've fixed that portion. The main issue is that, while in `my_task` it is able to loop through 1 round in `range(4)`, i'm met with a `asyncio.exceptions.CancelledError` when i'm trying to `await on_conn_lost` for the result. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry I have not yet had the pleasure of doing UDP in an asyncio environment.  Maybe you need to ask a different question for that.  You're right about as_completed - only now do I notice the little example in the docs where each future in the loop must be awaited.

Comment: The ProtocolFactroyUDP constructor takes only two arguments, but your lambda function in UDBClient s passing three.  This must cause an exception, and I'm not sure how your code is handling that.